# Java: How to select all descendants of a given ancestor on the Jtree?

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I would like to select an ancestor `DefaultMutableTreeNode` and get all descendant `DefaultMutableTreeNode` of this ancestor in the JTree.

I am using `TreeSelectionListener` to catch selection event on the current JTree.

Basically, what I would like to be able to do is, select an ancestor node, and be able to copy it's descendant tree into another ancestor.

Comment: confused: what's your main goal - copy or select? Not that much of a difference, like @Ray already mentioned, you'll need to walk the subtree and then copy/select each node individually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to walk the subtree recursively through the children() of the DMTN.

FWIW:

Maybe this will help a little, but ExampleDepot is a good site for Java example code, and they have a lot of Swing examples.

Here is a link to their set of JTree examples.  I hope you find what you need.

http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.swing.tree/pkg.html